# How to get the duration between two times and split it into minutes?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have this form in which teacher's can enter the **time and date** she is free for an interview. In the below example, the teacher is free for **an hour** on 16 January. After the teacher clicks close, the data will be entered in a **sql server table.**

What i want to do is take the data from database and show it on a student's page. However, students should see it after it has been **split**. This is because each interview is only **15 minutes**. From the split timings **( 02:15 to 02:20 etc )** , the student can choose which is his preferred time.

I have no idea how to phrase this question. I know it might be confusing but if anyone understands please help me!

[image]

Comment: Table Schema, sample data and expected output please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ayushi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting questions try to be specific, do you want help with SQL or ASP.net? Also, try to provide as much information as you can. As Squirrel says, post the table definitions and in/out data so people can try to help.

Comment: Why are the split timings 2:15 and 2:20 if the interview are 15 minutes? Or are you saying you want to display the possible available start times in 5 minute increments?

Comment: @RufusL - I'm guessing it's a typo and should be "2:15 and 2:30"

Comment: I think you already set your direction in your question. If those are the rules, then you'll have to store those blocks of time (aka "splits") by the stated increment (15 min).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get the duration between two times and split it into minutes?

The short answer is: You find the total minutes and divide it by the number of minutes in a segment (the interview length).

---

If I understand you correctly, you've read a date, a start time, and an end time from your database, and now you want to display the times in 15-minute increments from the start time up to (but not including) the end time.

If that's the case, here's a code snippet that might help. I have the dates hard-coded for the example, but the logic is that it uses `Enumerable.Range` to get a list of values starting at `0` with a count of `(total minutes between start and end time divided by 15)`, and then, for each of those values, it selects a new datetime by adding [15 times that number] of minutes to the start time.

So, for your example, since the total minutes are `60`, and then divided by `15` is `4`, the range would be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, then we multiply that number by `15` and add it to the start time, ending with: `start time + 0 = 2:00`, `start time + 15 = 2:15`, `start time + 30 = 2:30`, and `start time + 45 = 2:45`.

```
// Pretend we got these from the database
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("01/16/2019");
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse("2:00 PM");
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("3:00 PM");

// Interview length in minutes
int interviewLength = 15;

// Get a list of 15 minute increments starting at start time
List<DateTime> increments =
    Enumerable.Range(0, (int) (endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes / interviewLength)
        .Select(minutes => startTime.AddMinutes(minutes * interviewLength))
        .ToList();

// Show results to console
Console.WriteLine($"Start times available on {date.ToShortDateString()}:");
increments.ForEach(time => Console.WriteLine($"\t{time.ToShortTimeString()}"));

Console.ReadKey();
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

If some of that code seems confusing, the "old school" way to write this out (possibly easier to read) would look something like:

```
for (DateTime time = startTime; time < endTime; time = time.AddMinutes(15))
{
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToShortTimeString());
}
```